# Checking available heap memory dynamically from Perl

Tags: perl

I am running into the need to better balance my octrees based not just on spacial distribution but also on memory usage per branch. Whats the best way in Perl to check memory usage per object generated and then as a ratio of memory available to that process ?

Comment: Calculating memory usage of objects is difficult: parts can be nested or shared. How would you calculate `my @x = (1, 2, 3); my %h = (x => \@x)` (`@x` has refcount=2)?

Comment: I would expect both the array and the hash to be stored on the stack, not the heap, as they are not dynamic. Therefore I am not interested in the memory they would use.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the total_size function in Devel::Size:

```
use Devel::Size qw/total_size/;
print total_size {
    a => [1,2,4],
    b => [{
            x => 2,
            y => 3,
        }, undef, 123],
    c => 123,
}
# 975
```

You can get available memory from /proc/meminfo on linux.

Comment: This looks useful. I will see if it can cope with objects that I create on the heap.

Comment: IIRC almost everything you create in perl is stored on the heap.

Comment: When I last looked through the Perl source code I could see it tries to create as much as it can on the stack, presumably for performance and ease of management. However anything anonymous and of course any object you create is on the heap. I can pretty much figure out the stack usage simply by taking a guess at what the underlying C code would generate a long, short, etc and when it would pop them off the machines stack. However trying to do the same thing on the heap is more difficult. Clearly trees can be very large and I would be amazed if any of it is on the stack.

Comment: Re "When I last looked through the Perl source code I could see it tries to create as much as it can on the stack", Perl avoids the *C stack* as much as possible, allocating everything on the *C heap*, including function argument lists and every single variables. So yeah, it handles variables on the heap.

Comment: I agree somewhat, with that statement. However in perlguts http://search.cpan.org/~rjbs/perl-5.18.2/pod/perlguts.pod there are certainly enough cases where the stack is in play. If you think about it why would you not make use of the CPU stack ?

Comment: This is excellent. This Devel::Size class does indeed report heap usage stastics ( based on my experiments with it ). Thank you user user2243865, very helpful

Comment: @user1418706 There is no CPU stack. “The stack” in C is just a coherent piece of memory that can be used for allocations with little overhead (`malloc` incurs a large amount of bookkeeping, whereas a stack allocation just increments a pointer), which is also CPU-cache friendly. perl does not use the C stack, but has a few of it's own (most importantly the argument stack). For some datatypes, perl uses an *arena allocator* which exploits that the size of each allocation is statically known (it's between malloc and a stack). But from C's point of view, all of that happens on the heap.

Comment: This question has been answered.